# Load CycleJS with SystemJS

Tags: javascript, systemjs, es6-modules, cyclejs

I tried to load Cycle DOM from their CDN through SystemJS with something like:

```
System.config({
  map: {
    'cycle-dom': 'https://unpkg.com/@cycle/dom@17.1.0/dist/cycle-dom.js',
    'xstream': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xstream/10.3.0/xstream.min.js',
  }
});

System.import('cycle-dom', cycleDOM => {
    ...
});
```

But I quickly found out cycle-dom needs `xstream`. So I try to load both:

```
Promise.all([
  System.import('xstream'),
  System.import('cycle-dom')
])
.then(([xs, cycleDOM]) => {
  ...
});
```

But I still get the same error. It looks like `cycle-dom` is expecting `xstream` to exist on `window` when it's first loaded. So I tried:

```
System.import('xstream')
  .then(xs => window['xstream'] = xs)
  .then(() => System.import('cycle-dom'))
  .then(cycleDOM => {
    ...
  });
```

I feel like I'm going about this all wrong. How can I do this?

**Update:**

Following martin's advice below, I tried configuring `xstream` as a dependency of `cycle-dom`.

[Here's a jsbin that demonstrates.](https://jsbin.com/kawisihobo/edit?js,console,output) What I'm doing is loading cycle-run and cycle-dom and then running the example off the cycle home page.

But I get the error:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined"

Undefined in this case is `cycle-dom` trying to load `window['xstream']`, which isn't being loaded.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `System.import()` call returns a Promise so you need to put the callback into its `then()` method (the second parameter is [the parent name](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/system-api.md#systemjsimportmodulename--normalizedparentname---promisemodule); not a callback).

```
System.import('cycle-dom').then(function(cycleDOM) {
  console.log(cycleDOM);
});
```

This prints the module exports.

I don't have any experience with `cycle.js` so I can't tell whether this is enough or not. Nonetheless you can set this package dependencies with `meta` config:

```
System.config({
  map: {
    'cycle-dom': 'https://unpkg.com/@cycle/dom@17.1.0/dist/cycle-dom.js',
    'xstream': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xstream/10.3.0/xstream.min.js',
  },
  meta: {
    'cycle-dom': {
      deps: [
        'xstream'
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

Again, I don't know whether this is enough or not. The SystemJS documentation contains pretty well explained example how to load dependencies that need to register some global variables. See https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/module-formats.md#shim-dependencies

**Edit:**
In this case it's a little more complicated. The [`cycle-run.js`](https://unpkg.com/@cycle/run@3.1.0/dist/cycle-run.js) script is generated probably by `browserify` and you can see it contains a line as follows:

```
var xstream_1 = (typeof window !== "undefined" ? window['xstream'] : typeof global !== "undefined" ? global['xstream'] : null);
```

This checks whether `window['xstream']` exists when it's loaded. This means that the `xstream` has to be loaded before loading the `cycle-run.js` script. The way SystemJS works is that it loads the requested module and then loads its dependencies (you can see the order in Developer Tools). So it's the opposite order than you need (this is very similar to [my question on SystemJS GitHub page](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/1617)).

This means you need to restructure the import calls:

```
System.config({
  // ...
  meta: {
    'xstream': {
      format: 'global',
      exports: 'xstream',
    }
  }
});

System.import('xstream').then(function() {
  Promise.all([
    System.import('cycle-run'),
    System.import('cycle-dom'),
  ])
  .then(([cycle, cycleDOM]) => {
    // ...
  });
});
```

This registers the `xstream` before loading `cycle-run`. Also with the `meta` configuration for `xstream` this ensures that the `window.xstream` exists only inside these callbacks and doesn't leak to the global scope.

See your updated demo: https://jsbin.com/qadezus/35/edit?js,output

Also to use `format` and `exports` you need to use the newer SystemJS `0.20.*` and not `0.19.*`.

Comment: You're absolutely right, my first snipped was typed wrong. Too much working in node lately, I've gotten used to the callback approach again. Adding meta configs don't seem to fix this issue, though. I'm adding a jsbin that demonstrates.